# How to run Tomcat 7 using Maven 2 Tomcat plugin?

Tags: maven-2, maven, tomcat7, maven-tomcat-plugin

I am using **Maven 2** and I have an external **Tomcat 7**. I was wondering how to run Tomcat 7 from using Maven Tomcat plugin.

And does Maven Tomcat plugin in **Maven 3** runs the Tomcat 7 by default.

Thanks.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

This works for me: http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.1/

With this plugin config:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.1</version>
  <configuration>
    <path>/</path>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And running with

```
mvn clean install tomcat7:run
```

(Please note that `tomcat7:run`, not `tomcat:run`.)

Plugin documentation is here: http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.1/tomcat7-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html

For example, [the default value of `additionalConfigFilesDir`](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.1/tomcat7-maven-plugin/run-mojo.html#additionalConfigFilesDir) is `${basedir}/src/main/tomcatconf`, so if you put your configs into this directory it will be used on `tomcat7:run`.

`mvn -X tomcat7:run` prints the configration, for example:

```
[DEBUG] (f) additionalConfigFilesDir = /workspace/webtest1/src/main/tomcatconf
[DEBUG] (f) configurationDir = /workspace/webtest1/target/tomcat
...
[DEBUG] (f) path = /webtest1
...
[DEBUG] (f) port = 8080
[DEBUG] (f) project = ...:webtest1:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT @ /workspace/webtest1/pom.xml
...
[DEBUG] (f) warSourceDirectory = /workspace/webtest1/src/main/webapp
```

Note that `warSourceDirectory` points to `src` (not `target`), so it runs as an usual dynamic web project, you could change your JSPs, HTMLs and it will visible immediately. That's why the `target/tomcat/webapps` folder is empty.

Comment: whn i tried it, i got the exception: `WARNING: Unable to load class [org.codehaus.classworlds.ConfiguratorAdapter] to check against the @HandlesTypes annotation of one or more ServletContentInitializers.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.classworlds.ConfiguratorAdapter` any ideas ?

Comment: i posted about the exception here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7821622/unable-to-load-class-org-codehaus-classworlds-configuratoradapter-to-check-aga

Comment: another question is that when i tried to change the tomcat configuration directory as :  `<tomcatConfigurationFilesDirectory>
               D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.22\conf
               </tomcatConfigurationFilesDirectory>` it doesn't work, it still applies configuration from app\target\tomcat

Comment: do i have to configure the war directory, meaning the place to deploy war file to, coz the folder myapp\target\tomcat\webapps doesn't contain anything, so that when i try to open http:localhost:8080\ i got exceptions from url rewrite framework that there's no classes here

Comment: well i used mvn clean and then mvn tomcat7:run and everything works fine, and i have no idea how it's working

Comment: that tomcat7:run was very helpful. Had missed that fact and wondered why it still was running Tomcat 6.

Comment: Thanks mate, I wasted two days to find a proper documentation to get this plugin working. Your answer really helped

Comment: The method started the tomcat smoothly but soon I get "xxxx.servlet  cannot be cast to javax.servlet.Servlet", have no idea why.

Comment: @ChenLin: You should ask it as a separate question (with more context info).

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the [tomcat 7 plugin](https://github.com/t7mp/maven-t7-plugin)?

Comment: i tried it, but it gives me an exception: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7805464/unable-to-load-class-com-sun-jmx-mbeanserver-repositorysupport-to-check-agains