# Unable to load class [com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.RepositorySupport] to check against the @HandlesTypes

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, maven-2, maven, tomcat7

after migrating to tomcat **7.0.22**
and installing **t7mp** (**tomcat 7 plugin from google code**) i am running on **maven 2** btw
when trying to run **mvn t7:run**, i got the following exception:

```
WARNING: Unable to load class [com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanInstantiatorImpl] to check against the @HandlesTypes annotation of one or more ServletContentInitializers.
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2820)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1150)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1645)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1523)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.checkHandlesTypes(ContextConfig.java:2006)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:1969)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:1858)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1826)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1812)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1306)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:896)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:322)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5103)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:148)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:812)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:787)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:607)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1055)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:978)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1329)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:311)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:389)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:334)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1041)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:774)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:148)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1033)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:291)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:148)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:148)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:727)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:148)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:621)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
        at com.googlecode.t7mp.RunMojo.execute(RunMojo.java:52)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeStandaloneGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:569)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:539)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Oct 18, 2011 11:50:00 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig checkHandlesTypes
```

here's my configuration for t7mp:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>com.googlecode.t7mp</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-t7-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.9.6</version>
                <configuration>
                     <tomcatHttpPort>8081</tomcatHttpPort>
                     <tomcatShutdownPort>8008</tomcatShutdownPort>
                     <tomcatVersion>7.0.22</tomcatVersion>                                     
                </configuration>
</plugin>
```

so any ideas why i am getting this error, and how to solve it ?

**UPDATE:**

i got the same error when trying to run my external tomcat7 from eclipse.

Comment: Your project's runtime classpath is seriously messed up. Check your project's buildpath and/or the maven config. I can't post an answer as I don't use Maven and can't go in detail about that. Looking at [your](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1000194/fresh-dev) question history and the one of [your "friend"](http://stackoverflow.com/users/989301/mika) I have the impression that you (both?) didn't get the Maven concepts very right. I'd suggest to invest some more time in learning Maven first before trying to fiddle around with real projects.

Comment: @BalusC can you at least guide me to what is the problems with the classpath, and i will try to solve it .

Comment: Given the exception, you seem to have Glassfish-specific libraries in the webapp's runtime classpath. But you're running Tomcat server, not Glassfish server! As last resort, you can also just get rid of Maven altogether if you don't/can't grasp it at all for now, so that you can just work on the project with full and clear Eclipse-assisted control over the classpath.

Comment: well above exception was gone by excluding jmxtools,jmxri from the log4j library `<dependency>
   
   <groupId>log4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.15</version>
   <exclusions>
             <exclusion>
             <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
             <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
             <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
             <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
          </exclusions>
   
  </dependency>`

Comment: That's indeed a Glassfish-specific library.

Comment: but i am still getting the following one, any hints please : `WARNING: Unable to load class [Testing.MyTestTest] to check against the @HandlesTypes annotation of one or more ServletContentInitializers`. 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Testing.MyTestTest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well above exception was gone by excluding **jmxtools**,**jmxri** from the **log4j** library

```
<dependency> 
  <groupId>log4j</groupId> 
  <artifactId>log4j</artifactId> 
  <version>1.2.15</version> 
  <exclusions> 
    <exclusion> 
     <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId> 
     <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId> 
    </exclusion> 
     <exclusion> 
      <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId> 
       <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId> 
     </exclusion> 
  </exclusions> 
</dependency>
```