# Avoid version number from context root of web application

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, tomcat, web-applications

I've web application. I'm using maven to build this application. I get a war file when i build application: my-service-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war. While accessing the services over http, i have to make a call like this:

```
 http://localhost:8080/my-service-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/......
```

I don't want version number in my context name. I'm using tomcat as container. Do i have to set context root for this under Web-Inf as we do it in case of jboss ? Does it depend based on the type of container we use ?

Comment: You can set the context path on Tomcat: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276989/howto-set-the-context-path-of-a-web-application-in-tomcat-7-0

Comment: And you can also use the `path` configuration if you are using tomcat maven plugin: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7811435/664577

Comment: This should not matter because this is in-place container in Maven. This is not intended for production!

Comment: Is there any way to handle it in application itself rather than configuring at container level ? I don't want to rename the war file as suggested using maven (build file name).

Answer (score 4):

Using maven you can set a variable in your pom.xml file to store your final build name and in your war plugin configuration you pass it. Something like this:

```
<build>
  <finalName>my-service</finalName>
</build>
```

Then in your plugin configuration:

```
<plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.0</version>
     <configuration>
           <webappDirectory>/path_to_deploy_folder/${project.build.finalName}.war</webappDirectory>
     </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

Comment: No, this is not theright way. The only right way is by modifying the config of the tomcat maven plugin as layed out by Anthony Accioly.

Comment: Well since the question is mentioning MAVEN to build the application why this is not the right answer, or, at least a valid one?

Comment: I agree with Jorge, if only case is to remove version from url, what are cons of this answer?

Comment: It's a perfectly valid answer, IMO.

Comment: @JorgeCampos, it's Maven and **not** MAVEN.

Comment: @Michael-O Yeah, I know that, i just capitalize to emphasize my point :)

Comment: There is **bold** especially for that.

Answer (score 1):

You did not mention whether you are using maven to deploy into tomcat container. If you're creating a production environment you probably won't be using maven at least for local deployments. In that case I don't think it's a bad idea to rename your war file. For example  if you want you webapp root to be at https://mydomain.com/subdomain/myteam/myapp then simply rename my-service-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war to subdomain#myteam#myapp.war with '/' being replaced by '#'